# Login functionality: Shared preferences

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, sharedpreferences

```
package com.example.myapplication

import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.SharedPreferences
import android.icu.util.VersionInfo
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.renderscript.Sampler
import android.text.LoginFilter
import android.util.Log
import android.view.View
import android.widget.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingDeque

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {






    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val username = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.ET1).toString()
        val password = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.ET2).toString()

        val username1 = getSharedPreferences("username", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        username1.edit().putString("username","").apply()
        val password1 = getSharedPreferences("password", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        password1.edit().putString("password", "").apply()
        val rememberme = findViewById<CheckBox>(R.id.checkBox)
        val loginbutton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.LoginButton)
        val register = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView2)




        if(username.equals("admin")){

            val a = username1.getString(username,"").toString()
            Log.i("Usernmae is ", a)
            loginbutton.setOnClickListener {
                val intent = Intent(this, ListActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
            }

        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(this,"Invalid Credentials",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        rememberme.setOnCheckedChangeListener { buttonView, isChecked ->
            if (isChecked) {
                val pf = getSharedPreferences("checkbox", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
                val ed = pf.edit()
                ed.putString("remember", "True")
                ed.apply()
                Toast.makeText(this, "Checked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

            } else if (!isChecked) {
                val pf = getSharedPreferences("checkbox", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
                val ed = pf.edit()
                ed.putString("remember", "False")
                ed.apply()
                Toast.makeText(this, "Unchecked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }

        /*register.setOnClickListener {
            val intent =Intent(this, Registration:: class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }*/
    }


    }












        /*val pf = getSharedPreferences("checkbox", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        val checkbox = pf.getString("remember", "")




        }*/



        /*

            }

        }
    }*/
```

I am trying to add login functionality to my app.

Where user can register and his/her data is kept at their device only. Once they check the 'Remember Me' button they need not to login every time.

However,the code doesn't read the 'if' part of the code and always displays the message from 'else' section

Please help me.

Comment: You are resetting the username to empty string every time by adding this line    username1.edit().putString("username","").apply()

Comment: Could you explain me what is the `username` here 
`val username = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.ET1).toString()`
Is it an EditText or String from the EditText?

Comment: For anything like storing credentials, I would use `EncryptedSharedPreference` or a `Keystore`. Also, whatever PraveenSP wrote.

Comment: PraveenSP, can you suggest the code that I should write. I am quite new to this so not able to clearly understand.

Comment: Sonu Sourav that is an editText but I am converting it to string

Comment: Taseer can you share any details on that and how to use that

Comment: You can start by reading [this](https://developer.android.com/topic/security/data) and [this](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore)